# Flexbox column cropping image (on iOS only)

Tags: css, flexbox

**1)** I have been developing a site using flexbox CSS styling to control the site layout. I have been using the [FLA Framework](http://progressivered.com/fla) to write this site - same as [facebook.design](http://facebook.design).

Firebug and Chrome Inspector show no issues with the layout of the code, however on mobile iOS Safari and Chrome, the images are cropping when the flexbox `order` is being used. (as far as I can tell).

Steps I have taken to resolve this are to add the `-webkit-order: x;` to the stylesheet however this has no effect.

[image]

The website can be seen here: [LINK](http://business.point-reward.com)

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce the issue. Links to external resource tends to die and when they do, those questions will be useless for future users, also, we shouldn't have to parse through a full web site to find and figure out an issue you have.

Comment: I can, but is tricky when I am using a flex framework that the code is dependent on. I would just be deleting the code above and below and re-posting a fiddle. I am really appealing to see if there is anyone else experiencing the same and finding a fix. This has happened both with and without the framework but is only replicable on an iOS device - it looks fine on browsers and firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a iOS device so unable to check this, but have you check to change the overflow property to auto for mobile devices?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 40em){
  section.popup{
    overflow:auto;
  }
}
```